# Passing Date argument to function

Tags: javascript

How to pass argument of Date to another function? My code:

```
var myDate = new Date(data.GetOPCResult.DateTime.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
var datlabel = document.getElementById("ct");
datlabel.innerHTML = GetTime(myDate);
```

And GetTime function code:

```
function GetTime(DateTime) {
    var month = (DateTime.getMonth() < 10) ? "0" + (DateTime.getMonth() + 1) : (DateTime.getMonth() + 1);
    var day = (DateTime.getDate() < 10) ? "0" + DateTime.getMonth() : DateTime.getMonth();
    var hour = (DateTime.getHours() < 10) ? "0" + DateTime.getHours() : DateTime.getHours();
    var minute = (DateTime.getMinutes() < 10) ? "0" + DateTime.getMinutes() : DateTime.getMinutes();
    var second = (DateTime.getSeconds() < 10) ? "0" + DateTime.getSeconds() : DateTime.getSeconds();
    return DateTime.getDate() + "." + month + "." + DateTime.getFullYear() + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
}
```

Comment: You already did it correctly (regarding the syntax). If your code does "not work" then you have to tell us exactly what happens and what should happen.

Comment: In `function GetTime(Date)` - you don't use your Date parameter so the `myDate` that you pass in in `datlabel.innerHTML = GetTime(myDate);` is not used inside the function.

Comment: I just refresh my example code. Replace Date with DateTime...

Comment: In latest Chrome 13 I'm get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getMonth' of undefined. What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me

```
function GetTime(d) {
    var month = (d.getMonth() < 10) ? "0" + (d.getMonth() + 1) : (d.getMonth() + 1);
    var day = (d.getDate() < 10) ? "0" + d.getMonth() : d.getMonth();
    var hour = (d.getHours() < 10) ? "0" + d.getHours() : d.getHours();
    var minute = (d.getMinutes() < 10) ? "0" + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes();
    var second = (d.getSeconds() < 10) ? "0" + d.getSeconds() : d.getSeconds();

    return d.getDate() + "." + month + "." + d.getFullYear() + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
}

alert(GetTime(new Date()));
```

Are you sure you are passing a valid Date object? Try passing `new Date()` instead of myDate to your GetTime. If that works, your myDate variable is not a valid Date object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. A little re-factoring will help though.

```
function GetTime(date) {
    var day = zeroPad(date.getDate(), 2);
    var month = zeroPad(date.getMonth() + 1, 2);
    var year = zeroPad(date.getFullYear(), 4);
    var hour = zeroPad(date.getHours(), 2);
    var minute = zeroPad(date.getMinutes(), 2);
    var second = zeroPad(date.getSeconds(), 2);
    return day + "." + month + "." + 
        year + " " + hour + ":" + 
        minute + ":" + second;
}

function zeroPad(num, count) {
    var z = num + '';
    while (z.length < count) {
        z = "0" + z;
    }
    return z;
}
```

Also please check what is `data.GetOPCResult.DateTime`. I would say this will do.

```
var myDate = new Date( (data.GetOPCResult.DateTime || "")
                .replace(/-/g,"/")
                .replace(/[TZ]/g," ") );
```